# Git deleting files in merge

Tags: git, merge

I am new to git and am trying to perform a simple merge but can't seem to get it working.

I have a web code base that is reused across about 5 clients. Most of this code is the same, however there is for example a few config files and an uploads folder which is unique to each client.

So, I set out to try and create a solution that allows me to package up each site without having to manually upload the custom files each time.

Here is what I do:

`git checkout master`
`git checkout -b site1`

*Deletes all files except config files and uploads folder*

`git commit -a -m "Removed duplicates, remaining files are unique/custom"`
`git checkout master`
`git checkout -b temp`
`git merge site1`

It's at this point that I get stuck. The merge just deletes all of the files except the custom ones, where what I want it to do is simply merge in the custom files and leave the `master` files that were copied in from `checkout` alone.

Can anyone please tell me how to stop this from happening?

Comment: Given what you are trying to do with Git, i recommend that you first read a Git tutorial before trying to use it. You need to understand how a versionning system works.

Comment: @Derek What makes you think that I don't know how version control works? I'm not very experienced but I've read a number of a tutorials.

Comment: You seem to believe that the files that don't change between branches have to be deleted. No, you just leave them untouched and let the versionning system handle the differences.

Comment: @Derek That's not what I said, I'm talking about two different branches with different content that I want to merge together. My misunderstanding was in the `git commit` as pointed out by Tim's answer.

Comment: "config files and an uploads folder which is unique to each client". Good, you've identified some key file types. Now consider whether these files *should* be tracked. Configuration files generally should not: being able to change configuration on the fly is very useful. Instead, track a template file and instruct users to copy and modify it on install. Content generally shouldn't be tracked, either. IMO you should [ignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) these files entirely.

Comment: @jskidd3 then why did you delete the files that are identical between all your instances ? You don't have to delete any file on the site branches: a branch is not just a list of changed files, it's a full working copy with some files changed.

Comment: @Derek If that's the case, let's say I just `checkout -b site1` and don't remove any of the files, what would happen when I make changes to the `master` branch? Surely there's going to be conflict between `site1`'s old copy and the `master`?

Comment: @jskidd3 if you don't change these files on the site1 branch but only on the master branch, you will be able to merge master into site1 without conflicts. Conflicts only happen when you change the same file on the branches you are trying to merge.

Comment: @Derek Excellent, thank you very much. I didn't realize that - with that said I should be able to do this without deleting any files then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deployment-specific files you have 2 solutions :

### 1 - Don't put the config file on Git (preferred)

Instead of the config file, put a *dist* file with a sample config on git. For example, if your config file name is *config.ini*, then put a *config.ini.dist* on Git containing the same structure as the config file but with fake values (you don't want your server credentials to be on your versionning system).
Then when you deploy to your servers, copy the dist file to the real name of your config file and edit it with the proper values.

### 2 - Create a branch for each environment

I think that's what you were trying to do here.
Create a branch from master and edit your config files in this branch with the appropriate values for the config file. Don't touch any other file (and don't delete them!!). **You won't ever merge these branches back to master.**
Continue working on bugfixes and features on the other branches and merge to master.

When you are done coding and ready to deploy, merge the master branch to each of the env-specific branches. Update your code on each server by checking out the proper branch.
This means that you will have a lot of merging to do on each deployment, and that you will store your database credentials on your versionning system (baaaad). Go for the first solution.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I can get away with not putting the config file on Git, but what would you recommend that I do about content like images? Each site has its own logo file and some of its own uploaded images. Is the only way around this to manually upload, or would the 'branch for each environment' option be better here?

Comment: You have 3 different things here: user uploaded content, site-specific images and environment-specific configuration. User uploaded content should not be on your versionning system, they should be ignored by your gitignore file. Site specific images can be on site-specific branches. Since you seem to have one site per server, site-specific branches and environmen-specific branches could be the same in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Because you did `git commit -a -m "Removed duplicates, remaining files are unique/custom"`, only the custom files are left in that branch.

Of course, when you merge with that, it removes everything except for the custom files.

Git merge does not combine files together in a branch, it combines commits. Therefore because you merge with the commit that "Removed duplicates, remaining files are unique/custom", the merge does exactly that, too.

I think you're going to have to manually copy the custom files to the new branch. Unless you have a commit somewhere that only adds the custom files, in that case you could cherry-pick that commit in the new branch.

Comment: Has `-A` been removed from git since v2.5 ? Can't find anything in git help commit ...

Comment: @edi9999 My mistake, I meant -a in my question, Tim probably copied that line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim. I really need to come up with a way that means I don't have to manually copy, I'm going to look into what you said about committing somewhere else with the custom files. Thanks.

Comment: Because you have 5 different "projects" with each their own custom files, you have no choice but to do some stuff by hand somewhere. Custom files don't generate themselves :-)